# GetWindowRect for a UWP process from Desktop

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to get access to the co-ordinates of a UWP app process from my desktop C# app (or console, if that works). Is this possible? More specifically, I need to get the current co-ordinates of Microsoft Edge on the screen.

GetWindowRect always returns 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. The UWP apps run in sandbox. It's not allowed to communicate between the app's process. So, this API will not work for UWP apps.

Comment: @BenWebb Yes. Sure.

Comment: So is there really no alternative?

Comment: @RadialApps In UWP, you could get its own position. But if you want to get its position from another app(different process), you cannot do it.